# JUNIT giving NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception for a bean which not annotated with @Service but mentioned in Application Context

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

In my project in Application context "context:component-scan" is mentioned and there is a class (e.g `A`) which is not annotated with `@Service`, but declared in Application Context. And other classes are annotated with (`@Service`, `@Component`,..).
I this `A` class is Autowired in another class, When I execute this project, It runs fine, But it gives `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for `Merger` class when I execute it with jUNIT.

When i annotate A class with `@Service`, it is working in JUNIT also.

#### In Summary

**Not Working**

no autowire

`class A{}`  Declared in Application context.

```
@Service
Class B{@Autowire A a;}
```

Normal run works fine, but JUNIT gives `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

**Working**

```
@Service
Class A{}  Declared in Application context.

@Service
Class B{@Autowire A a;}
```

JUNIT and Normal run both works fine.

Note: I can not annotate Class `A` with `@Service`, because there are many classes of this type, I just want to write JUNIT for them, Kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: While running `Junit`, is your `application-context.xml` getting loaded.

Comment: Yes,it is getting loaded.

Comment: pls post the xml's as well, test.xml etc